# Swift - insert item in TableView from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates

I am having a problem where I seem to add items to a `tableView` in another `ViewController` but they don't appear if presenting the VC.

I am also having different `tableViews` which makes it a bit more difficult:

This is inside my first `ViewControllerA` from where I can access the 2nd `ViewControllerB`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // if indexPath.item is less than data count, return a "Content" cell
    if indexPath.item < wishListTitlesArray.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

        cell.cellLabel.text = wishListTitlesArray[indexPath.item]

        cell.buttonView.setImage(wishListImagesArray[indexPath.item], for: .normal)

        cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {

            // track selected index
            self.currentWishListIDX = indexPath.item

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as! WishlistViewController
            // set image
            vc.wishlistImage.image = self.wishListImagesArray[indexPath.item]
            // set label
            vc.wishlistLabel.text = self.wishListTitlesArray[indexPath.item]
            // set wishlist
            vc.theTableView.wishList = self.userWishListData[indexPath.item]

            vc.currentWishListIDX = self.currentWishListIDX

            vc.userWishListData = self.userWishListData

            vc.theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        return cell
    }

func insertWish(){

    insertWishDelegate?.insertWish(wishName: popUpView.whishName!, idx: selectedWishlistIDX!, currentWishlistIDX: currentWishListIDX,data: userWishListData)

    // save Wish to database -> DataHandler
    saveWish()

}
```

And this is inside my 2nd ViewController:

```
func insertWish(wishName: String, idx: Int, currentWishlistIDX: Int, data: [[Wish]]) {
    // append the new wish to the user's currently selected wishlist
    var wishes: [Wish] = data[idx]
    wishes.append(Wish(withWishName: wishName, checked: false))
    userWishListData[currentWishlistIDX] = wishes
    // set the updated data as the data for the table view
    theTableView.wishList = userWishListData[currentWishlistIDX]
    theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Presenting the 2nd ViewController works just fine. All the variables I pass are the right ones. The only problem I have is that I am not able to insert a "Wish". There is no error or something. The user can add Wishes from the first ViewController:

```
@objc func wishButtonTapped(){
    dismissPopUpView()
    insertWish()
}
```

For the whole project you can look at my git (very messy though): [Git Project](https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist)

I probably miss something very basic but I can not get behind what it is so I am very grateful for every help :)

Comment: I took a quick look at your project.  I don't have a direct answer for your question but I recommend moving your data model into a class that manages it to reduce complexity in the view controllers.  Doing that will probably make your current problem irrelevant.

Comment: @PhillipMills that sounds good, but I am not quite sure what you mean by that, I am still quite new. Could you maybe elaborate on this?:)

Comment: I usually create an object that is responsible for any state information that's shared among other classes in my application.  View controllers don't store copies of that information and don't act on it.  Instead they tell the data model object to do an insert, delete, or whatever.  When they need to display data, they ask the model object for it.  That way, there's only one source of truth for the data and no need to synchronize local controller updates.

Comment: @PhillipMills should I use a `struct` or `class`  for my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot work because you are accessing UI elements in `vc` which are not connected (yet) right after instantiating the view controller.

Secondly you are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays for the data source. Never do that. Create a custom struct to hold all parameters of one item (in the code below called *`Item`*) and use **one** data source array (called *`datasourceArray`*).

Then assign the item to a temporary variable (`wishList` in `vc`) and assign the values to the UI elements in `viewDidLoad`

This example assumes that the values from the three arrays (`image`, `title` and `data`) are in one instance of the custom struct. You have to redesign the entire data model. In the closure pass the `Item` instance to `vc`

```
cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {

        // track selected index
        self.currentWishListIDX = indexPath.item

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as! WishlistViewController
        vc.wishlist = datasourceArray[indexPath.item]
        vc.currentWishListIDX = self.currentWishListIDX
        vc.userWishListData = self.userWishListData
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and in vc in `viewDidLoad` populate the UI elements and reload the table view

```
var wishList : Item!

override func viewDidLoad()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    wishlistImage.image = wishList.image
            // set label
    wishlistLabel.text = wishList.title
            // set wishlist
    theTableView.wishList = wishList.data
    theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: ok, that will be quite a lot to do :D But I will give it a try and reach out again if it is not working. Thanks!